# Redshift - Printing output of variable

Tags: python, python-3.x, variables, amazon-redshift

I am trying to fetch the count of rows from a table and have it printed it. I am doing it as below:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT count (*) table limit 30""")
df = cursor.fetchall()
```

I am trying to print the output of the above as below:

```
for num in df:
    print(num)
```

This is returning '1' though the expected output is 30. Could anyone advice as to where am I going wrong. Thanks

Comment: you should probably tag this question as python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you want to print the value of the first (and only) column in the result set, you should be using this:

```
cursor = db.cursor()
cursor.execute("""SELECT COUNT(*) AS cnt FROM table LIMIT 30""")
row = cursor.fetchone()
if row is not None:
    print(df["cnt"])
```

If this still returns a count of `1`, then there is another possible explanation.  Your table could coincidentally have just a single record in it.  `LIMIT 30` does not mean 30 records always get returned, just that a *maximum* of 30 records gets returned.

Side note: Using `LIMIT` without `ORDER BY` is fairly meaningless.  If you limit, you should generally also sort.

Comment: thanks tried this but it returns (30,). How could I just display 30.

Comment: @scottmartin You may try assigning an alias to the count in your query, and then access it when you print the row.  But, I am surprised my first answer did not work.